# JDBC ResultSet Cusor Position

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cursor, resultset

I have inherited some third party code using an old version of org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver jdbc mysql driver class against a mysql database.

The code appears to perform an executeQuery, storing the ResultSet returned and then using ResultSet.getString("FieldName").

Obviously the cursor is positioned before the first record in this set and you would normally perform a next.. but given that I can't recompile the third party code, I cannot do this.

Can anybody suggest a configuration setting that would position the cursor at the first record or a different jdbc mysql driver and result set that would work in this way?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: I don't think you'll find any configuration setting that fixes such a bug in the code. Why can't you recompile it?

Comment: because it's third-party.. I only have a license to use it.

Comment: Humm... And, can you rewrite this bad method in your new class or this method is final?

Comment: Paul.. I can't use the source.. it's not mine, hence I can't re-write, wrap etc as I mentioned.

Comment: Do you have control over the JDBC url?

Comment: Hi Mark, I can configure the driver class and can replace the lib files so yes. I am effectively setting up the hosting of this application.

I realise this isn't the norm and just hoped somebody may have been able to suggest a quick fix. May be able to wrap the jdbc jar?

Comment: I guess you might be able to use the MySQL sources, intentionally create a bug that it is already positioned on the first row and then use that version of the driver instead of the official one. Wrapping or proxying the driver will also work, but it might be a lot of work to correctly forward all calls to the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand, but hopfully this helps:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/navigate-result-sets.htm

Specifically this part:

```
// Move cursor to the first row.
  System.out.println("Moving cursor to the first row...");
  rs.first();
```

Hopefully it helps, but i'm just a bit unclear about the actual question.

Comment: Sebastian, I can't recompile.. hence I can't alter the code. This is why I was asking if there is any configuration that could alter the cursors initial position. JB has pointed out that there is not.